# Replace a custom Tag with a Partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been trying to replace a custom tag I have in a selection of HTML with a partial.

In my HTML I have [gallery 2] (2 being the ID of the gallery)

I have been trying to work out a way to find the [gallery 2] and replace it with the output of the partial gallery passing the ID of 2 through to the gallery partial so that it loads the correct images.

Does anyone have any idea how I might be able to do this? I have thought about using a simple string replace, however I am not sure how to call the output of the partial to replace the custom [gallery 2] tag in my HTML.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can pass variables via the local option to the partial

```
render partial: "form", locals: {user: @current_user, id: @current_user.id}
```

Now you can use `user` and `id` within the partial.

Comment: Thanks mate, I was mainly concerned with getting the [gallery 2] part out of the HTML for use in the partial in the first place.